# Результаты AJAX запроса слетают после обновления страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

Всем доброго времени суток.
На карточках с товарами есть кнопка "добавить в избранное" (пустое/заполненное сердечко), реализованная с помощью AJAX-запросов. Все отлично работает, но при обновлении страницы верстка слетает на изначальную, что вроде как логично. Придумал небольшой костыль в HTML файле, который вроде решил проблему с обновлением страницы, но нет возможности тогглить кнопку туда-сюда.
Собственно, сами функции-представления:

```
# Функция-представление добавления позиции/товара в избранное
@profile_bp.route('/favourites/add')
@login_required
def add_to_favourites():
    food_id = request.args.get('id')
    food = Food.query.get_or_404(food_id)
    current_user.favs.append(food)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'id': food.id, 'result': 'success'})

# Функция-представление удаления позиции/товара из избранного.
@profile_bp.route('/favourites/delete')
@login_required
def delete_from_favourites():
    food_id = request.args.get('id')
    food = Food.query.get_or_404(food_id)
    current_user.favs.remove(food)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'id': food.id, 'result': 'success'})
```

Два корявеньких скрипта (скрипт для удаления аналогичен этому, только с добавление/удалением классов наоборот):

```
$(function() {
    $('.add-to-favs').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var food_id = $this.attr('id').slice(3,);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/profile/favourites/add',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {id: food_id},
            success: function() {
               $this.removeClass('add-to-favs');
               $this.addClass('delete-from-favs');
               $this.find('.bi-heart').removeClass('bi-heart').addClass('bi-heart-fill');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

И собственно костыль в HTML (т.е. если товар у юзера в БД находится в избранном, то выползает кнопка для удаления, если нет в избранном, то выползает кнопка для добавления):

```
{% if food not in current_user.favs %}
    <button type="button" class="add-to-favs btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" id="fav{{ food.id }}">
        <i class="bi bi-heart"></i>
    </button>
{% else %}
    <button type="button" class="delete-from-favs btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" id="fav{{ food.id }}">
        <i class="bi bi-heart-fill"></i>
    </button>
{% endif %}
```

И вот с этим костылем, если добавить товар в избранное, то AJAX-запрос сработает, классы изменятся, но если я нажму еще раз, чтобы удалить из избранного, то он все равно будет пытаться добавить его, выдав 500 ошибку. Чтобы обратно удалить/добавить товар, приходится перезагрузить страницу.

Comment: Пожалуйста, ответьте на собственный вопрос, а не изменяйте сам вопрос

Answer (score 0):

UPD:
В общем-то проблема решена.
В HTML теперь просто одна кнопка:

```
<button type="button" class="favourites btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" id="fav{{ food.id }}">
    <i class="bi bi-heart"></i>
</button>
```

Скрипты:

```
$(function favourites() {
    $('.favourites').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var food_id = $this.attr('id').slice(3,);
        var url_to_add = '/profile/favourites/add';
        var url_to_delete = '/profile/favourites/delete';
        if ($this.hasClass('added')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url_to_delete,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {id: food_id},
                success: function() {
                    $this.removeClass('added');
                    $this.find('.bi-heart-fill').removeClass('bi-heart-fill').addClass('bi-heart');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: url_to_add,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {id: food_id},
                success: function() {
                    $this.addClass('added');
                    $this.find('.bi-heart').removeClass('bi-heart').addClass('bi-heart-fill');
                }
            });
        };
    });
});

function get_user_favourites() {
    var api_url = '/profile/favourites/api';
    $.getJSON(api_url, function(json) {
        if (json !== null) {
            for (let food_id of json) {
                element = $(`.favourites#fav${food_id}`);
                element.addClass('added');
                element.find('.bi-heart').removeClass('bi-heart').addClass('bi-heart-fill');
            };
        };
    });
};

$(function() {
    get_user_favourites();
});
```

Проверяем, есть ли у элемента класс "added". Если есть, то удаляем, если нет, то добавляем. Через функцию-представление получаем JSON с id товаров, которые есть в избранном у юзера и соответствующим элементам добавляем класс "added" и обновляем кнопку.
И функция-представление:

```
@profile_bp.route('/favourites/api')
@login_required
def get_favourites_api():
    user_favourites = [food.id for food in current_user.favs]
    return jsonify(user_favourites)
```

Насколько вообще это решение адекватно? Есть ли пути получше?